# Setting Default Launcher to Continue Last Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher

I'm working on Kiosk mode in Android and my application has multiple Activities. Lets say they are Activity A, Activity B, Activity C.

I'm setting Default Launcher in Activity A. Here is how I do it.

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, FakeLauncherActivity.class);
packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
selector.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(selector);

packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

But my main activity is Activity B. So whenever I'm in Activity B or Activity C, home button relaunches Activity A. Rather than doing this, I want it to continue to my last Activity and does not relaunch it from Activity A.

Here is my manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="com.bambulabs.codebase.Models.Global"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon">

    <activity
        android:name="com.bambulabs.codebase.ActivityA"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bambulabs.codebase.ActivityB"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bambulabs.codebase.ActivityC"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
    </activity>

</application>
```

How can I accomplish it?

Note: I don't want to use an extra Activity to decide where to continue to app.

Comment: Why don't you create a splash activity as launcher screen and decide in splash which activity should open...You can save state of last opened activity in preference and as saved preference open activity respectively

Comment: I actually find this way too ugly. If there is something I miss, I want to learn it. But of course If I can't find a proper way, I will do it like you said. @SanjayMajoka

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

All I did is moving **launchMode="singleInstance"** attribute to application level in manifest and making ActivityA **launchMode="singleTop"**!

Here is working manifest file:

```
<application
android:name="com.bambulabs.codebase.Models.Global"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
tools:replace="android:icon"
android:launchMode="singleInstance">

<activity
    android:name="com.bambulabs.codebase.ActivityA"
    android:configChanges="locale"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="com.bambulabs.codebase.ActivityB"
    android:configChanges="locale"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="com.bambulabs.codebase.ActivityC"
    android:configChanges="locale"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
</activity>

</application>
```

For more details about launchMode attribute : https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en